# three.js Unproject camera within group

Tags: camera, three.js

I have a camera as child within a Group object and I need to get the origin/direction:

```
var cameraRig = new THREE.Group();
cameraRig.add( cameraPerspective );
cameraRig.add( cameraOrtho );
scene.add( cameraRig );

function relativeMousePosition () {
    var canvasBoundingBox = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.5);
    mouse3D.x = ((mouseX - 0) / canvasBoundingBox.width) * 2 - 1;
    mouse3D.y = -((mouseY - 0) / canvasBoundingBox.height) * 2 + 1;
    return mouse3D;
}

cameraRig.position.set(89,34,91);
cameraRig.lookAt(something.position);
cameraPerspective.position.set(123,345,123);

var dir = relativeMousePosition().unproject(camera).sub(cameraPerspective.position).normalize();
var origin = cameraPerspective.position;
```

The above code gives a origin + direction with the context of the cameraRig. When I exclude the camera out, having the scene as direct parent, it gives me the world origin/direction which I want. So how to incorporate the cameraRig to get world origin/direction, so I can do picking or whatever?

**FIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/647qzhab/1/

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comment by Falk:

```
var dir = relativeMousePosition().unproject(camera).sub(cameraPerspective.getWorldPosition()).normalize();
var origin = cameraPerspective.getWorldPosition();
```

The result is better, but not yet fully satisfiing, as the camera rotation seems not applied yet.

Comment: You could use ```camera.getWorldPosition()``` and ```camera.getWorldRotation()``` for that.

Comment: `camera.getWorldPosition()` seems the pretty right thing. It let the origin being correct. But I dont know yet how to use the camera.getWorldRotation(), It returns an Euler rotation, no idea how to apply that on the direction... Hint appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, I wasnt paying attention. There is ```camera.getWorldDirection()``` too, which would be what you want ;-)

Comment: hmm, I tried `camera.getWorldDirection()` allready. It gives me the world direction at the center of the camera view. But I need the direction of the mouse pointer based on the camera world projection/rotation. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I need to update matrixWorld for the cameraRig:

```
cameraRig.position.set(89,34,91);
cameraRig.lookAt(something.position);
cameraPerspective.position.set(123,345,123);

cameraRig.updateMatrixWorld(true);
cameraPerspective.updateMatrixWorld(true);
```